# How to remove a certain field from map cloud firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase

I continue to develop a directory application and now I need to delete a specific line in the map from cloud firestore.There is my database:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Hdx.jpg)
I need to remove field with key "2324141" or change its value.
I know about this method:

```
"2324141": FieldValue.delete()
```

But how do I get into the map and delete field or change the value?
thanks!

Here is my model of Object:

```
class ObjectInFB: Codable {
var objectFromPartsCatalogueListCode: String?
var countOfCurrentObjectInShoppingCart: Int = 1}
```

Here is func, where i save object in users shoppingBag:

```
    func addToUserShoppingCartFB(user: User?, object: ObjectInFB, count: Int){
    
    guard let user = user else { return }
    
    let objectReadyToBeWriten = [
        "UserEmail":"\(user.email!)",
        "shoppingCart" : ["\(object.objectFromPartsCatalogueListCode!)" : FieldValue.increment(Int64(count))]] as [String : Any]
    db.collection("users")
        .document("\(user.uid)")
        .setData(objectReadyToBeWriten, merge: true)
        { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {}
        }
}
```

And after the user in their cart in the application clicks "remove from cart" I want to delete an object from their cart in Firebase. I can only remove any field from the document, but how can I remove a field from the nested ShoppingCart?

```
       func removeShoppingCartFB(object: ObjectInFB, user: User?){
    db.collection("users").document(user!.uid).updateData([
        "shoppingCart": ["\(object.objectFromPartsCatalogueListCode!)" : FieldValue.delete()],
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error updating document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully updated")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Firebsse? Which service are you referring to?

Comment: Cloud firestore.

Comment: Run a search over your dataset to find a specific document that matches the key you are referring to.

Comment: how to do it - this is my question

Comment: What code have you attempted? We are not a code writing service and don't know how your Firestore is structured. If you can provide some code, we can get an idea of what you're attempting to do and may be able to provide a solution. Also see [Delete Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) which will provide some good overall information.

Comment: Thanks, I added more information to my question above.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include structures *in* the question. If the link breaks (which they do) then future readers will have no idea what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to delete a field within a map, it can be accessed through dot notation. For example suppose your structure looks like this

```
users
   uid_0
      UserEmail: "test@test.com"
      shoppingCart  (a map)
         2324141: 10
         122323424: 13
```

and we want to remove the 2324141 field. Here's the Swift code to do that

```
let myCollection = self.db.collection("users")
let myDoc = myCollection.document("uid_0")
myDoc.updateData( ["shoppingCart.2324141": FieldValue.delete(),
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully updated")
    }
}
```